# Resolving anomalous string to float operation on a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, file-io

I have a code that takes a .csv file and reads the values and prints it out. 
The contents of the .csv file are -

```
55
100
200
500
500
150
```

I am using the `stof` method to cast strings into floats like this -

```
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DataStore.size(); i++)
        cout << stof(DataStore[i]) << endl;
```

but in this case I only get the output as

```
55
```

instead of -

```
55
100
200
500
500
150
```

I am new to C++ so I'm pretty sure there's something trivial that I'm missing - but unable to figure it out.

Minimal Reproducible Code -

```
    string line;
    vector<string> DataStore;
    {

        ifstream file("test.csv");
        while (getline(file, line, ','))
        {
            DataStore.push_back(line);
            getline(file, line);
        }

    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DataStore.size(); i++)
        cout << stof(DataStore[i]) << endl;
```

Contents of `test.csv` are as follows -

```
55
100
200
500
500
150
```

Comment: I don't understand where your problem is. Could it be that parsing a string into a float is what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that is my problem. The last few lines discuss the problem and the erroneous output that I'm getting.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, @UlrichEckhardt I have streamlined my question and will add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @PyWalker2797 The code seems sufficiently minimal, but it is not complete anymore. It should be such that we can copy paste it into our IDE and compile it without change. That means a complete `int main()` and all necessary prelude like `#include`s etc.

Comment: Your `getline()` calls don't match. Is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (getline(file, line, ','))
```

This reads from the file until the it encounters a comma. There are no commas in your file, so the whole file will be read into `line`, this `line` is inserted into `DataStore` and the loop does not iterate any further, because there is nothing left to be read for the next `getline`.

Therefore `DataStore.size()` will be one and in the single iteration the whole file's contents are passed to `stof`, which will form the parsed number from the beginning until it encounters something not part of a valid number, here the newline. The result will be `55`. This is printed and the loop exits.

You seem to want to read line-by-line. This is done by `getline` without third argument (or third argument equal `'\n'`). Additionally there is a stray `getline`, the purpose of which I don't know.

```
string line;
vector<string> DataStore;
{

    ifstream file("test.csv");
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        DataStore.push_back(line);
    }

}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DataStore.size(); i++)
    cout << stof(DataStore[i]) << endl;
```

---

Note that you can directly read the numbers from the file into a `std::vector`:

```
ifstream file("test.csv");
vector DataStore(istream_iterator<double>(file), {});
```

This requires `#include<iterator>` and before C++17 the `vector` type needs to be specified: `vector<double>`

It reads white-space separated numbers until the end of file.

Comment: Thank you, I was actually going through the documentation for ```getline``` and understood the use of the ```delim``` parameter. Your answer makes it much clearer, thank you very much.